# Caius Cosades won't talk to me

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I just started a new game when I went to the Stilt Strider to get to Balmora. I went to the Corner Club to ask Caius Cosades' location. I went up the stairs all the way to his house and went. But then I couldn't talk to him about the package because he said:

> WHAT! Divayth Fry is dead? And you were responsible for him? He was the only one woith the solution of the cure for coropus. Get out and NEVER come back again! I don't care what the Emperor says! I don't care about your excuses! GET OUT!
>
> [This path is blocked]

And then I only have the option to exit the dialogue.

He says that dialogue when I killed Divayth Fyr, but I didn't kill him and besides I just started the game and I don't know where Tel Fyr is! Will please someone help me with the solution?

Comment: Are you using any mods? Is Morrowind fully patched? Are the expansions installed? What platform are you playing on? I doubt any of these questions will solve this problem, but they should help others with troubleshooting.

Comment: I was looking up if the NPC could have died by accident, but apparently he has the highest level and health of the base game. http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Divayth_Fyr so no idea what happend there. I guess mods, or bugged install. You could try restarting your game and see if it happens again.

Comment: Did you talk to caius a lot without handing over the package? That causes him to dislike you.

Comment: @Ids how can I do that? Of course before you can go anywhere else, you have to talk to the captain to get the package there's no other way around. Yes, I have the package.

Comment: @twobugs I play vanilla Morrowind.

Comment: I have no idea how you do that, have not played morrowind in ages. Just what it said on the UESP wiki. You could try teleporting towards the guy that is reported dead. But if you just play vanilla, something pretty strange went wrong. Did you kill him in a different save game? Perhaps there is a variable that does not get set correctly.

Comment: Okay I went to Tel Fyr right now. When I talked to one of the Dummer, she said I killed someone and she started to attack me. I went up to where Divayth Fyr is and I found his body. Weird I didn't kill him.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32065/discussion-between-jim-and-ids).

Answer (score 1):

Well, as your comments reveal, somehow, Divayth Fyr *is* dead, which means the game is working as intended, and to complete the Main Quest with this character, you'll have to take the Backpath, as documented on various places, like the [UESP Wiki](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Yagrum_Bagarn_and_Wraithguard).

Or just reset. Since it seems like you're only at the Deliver Package part, so resetting isn't hard? Unless you spent a LOT of time wandering around beforehand?